# No consigo acceder a un valor concreto de un item en java

Tags: java

Buenas,

Necesito acceder al valor dentro de un item de java. Empiezo inicializando un `ArrayList<Item>` de la siguiente manera:

```
ArrayList<Item> games = MicrosoftStore.TodaInfoJuegos(countries, urls);
```

Ese arrayList lo recorro con un bucle foreach, ya que está compuesto de `items` que tienen la siguiente estructura (es un ejemplo):

```
Name: DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round Character: Zack
Type: ---
Descripcion Castellano: Descarga este DLC para poder usar a Zack en la versi&oacute;n gratuita de DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round: Luchadores b&aacute;sicos. Este DLC podr&iacute;a ofrecerse como prueba gratuita durante un tiempo limitado en el futuro.
Descripcion Inglés: Download this to use Zack in DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round: Core Fighters.
Descripcion Pegi: Online Interactions Not Rated by the ESRB; Partial Nudity; Sexual Themes; Violence; 
Edad Pegi: 16+
Edad Pegi USA: Mature 17+
Microsoft Store ID: c3lcm7jmcs4q
Microsoft Store URL: c3lcm7jmcs4q
```

Así recorro el ArrayList:

```
for (Item game : games) {
    String code = game.get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL);
    //código en el que trabajo con la variable code
}
```

El caso es que cada vez que recorro el bucle foreach quiero acceder al valor de `Microsoft Store ID` pero soy incapaz.

El valor de `Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL` es `"Microsoft Store URL"`, simplemente que lo tengo en otra clase distinta y lo llamo de esa forma.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: *...que tienen la siguiente estructura ...* puede poner la clase `item`, supongamos que `MicrosoftStoreID` es el nombre de una variable, usted tiene por ejemplo algun getter para consultar ese dato?. o esa "estructura" es un String y quiere recuperar solo esa parte, es que asi como esta por lo menos yo no se lo que es, tampoco se muesta que es `game.get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL);` y como funciona.Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estás necesitando de un [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), es lo que se suele usar en Java para almacenar valores relacionados por clave - > valor, como es el caso que muestras. Los valores pares son introducidos en el mapa, una vez creado, usando el método `put`. Los mapas no admiten claves duplicadas, o sea, los valores de la izquierda no pueden ser duplicados. Podrás ver más detalles en la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

En el ejemplo verás la forma de leer un valor por su nombre de clave. Y verás dos formas de leer el mapa completo, antes y después de Java 8.

Puedes adaptar tu Mapa a cualquier clase, introducir sus valores en arrays, en la base de datos o donde quieras:

[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/GKIR89645)

**Código**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         String VALUE_MSSTORE_URL = new String ("Microsoft Store URL");
         Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put("Name", "DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round Character: Zack");
         map.put("Type", "---");
         map.put("Descripcion Castellano", "Descarga este DLC para poder usar a Zack en la versión gratuita de DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round...");
         map.put("Descripcion Inglés", "Download this to use Zack in DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round: Core Fighters.");
         map.put("Descripcion Pegi", "Online Interactions Not Rated by the ESRB; Partial Nudity; Sexual Themes; Violence;");
         map.put("Edad Pegi", "16+");
         map.put("Edad Pegi USA", "Mature 17+");
         map.put("Microsoft Store ID", "c3lcm7jmcs4q");
         map.put("Microsoft Store URL", "c3lcm7jmcs4q");

         System.out.println("\nBUSCANDO VALOR POR NOMBRE DE KEY\n");   

         System.out.println(map.get(VALUE_MSSTORE_URL));

         System.out.println("\nLEYENDO TODO EL MAPA: ANTES DE JAVA 8\n");
             for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) 
         {
              System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
         }


         System.out.println("\nLEYENDO TODO EL MAPA: JAVA 8\nforEach y lambda\n");

         map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Key : " + k + " Value : " + v));

    }
}
```

**Resultado**

```
BUSCANDO VALOR POR NOMBRE DE KEY

c3lcm7jmcs4q

LEYENDO TODO EL MAPA: ANTES DE JAVA 8

Key : Descripcion Pegi Value : Online Interactions Not Rated by the ESRB; Partial Nudity; Sexual Themes; Violence;
Key : Edad Pegi USA Value : Mature 17+
Key : Type Value : ---
Key : Descripcion Inglés Value : Download this to use Zack in DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round: Core Fighters.
Key : Microsoft Store ID Value : c3lcm7jmcs4q
Key : Edad Pegi Value : 16+
Key : Microsoft Store URL Value : c3lcm7jmcs4q
Key : Descripcion Castellano Value : Descarga este DLC para poder usar a Zack en la versión gratuita de DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round...
Key : Name Value : DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round Character: Zack

LEYENDO TODO EL MAPA: JAVA 8
forEach y lambda

Key : Descripcion Pegi Value : Online Interactions Not Rated by the ESRB; Partial Nudity; Sexual Themes; Violence;
Key : Edad Pegi USA Value : Mature 17+
Key : Type Value : ---
Key : Descripcion Inglés Value : Download this to use Zack in DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round: Core Fighters.
Key : Microsoft Store ID Value : c3lcm7jmcs4q
Key : Edad Pegi Value : 16+
Key : Microsoft Store URL Value : c3lcm7jmcs4q
Key : Descripcion Castellano Value : Descarga este DLC para poder usar a Zack en la versión gratuita de DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round...
Key : Name Value : DEAD OR ALIVE 5 Last Round Character: Zack
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me sirvió!

Comment: @JetLagFox Me alegro. Un saludo.